# Ubuntu 16.04.3 dual booted with Windows 10 can't connect to internet (both wifi and ethernet don't work)

Tags: 16.04, networking, dual-boot, internet, ethernet

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.3, I noticed that ethernet does not work and that the wifi tab says "No network devices available," even though there are many wifi connections around. On windows 10, I can connect to the internet via wifi and internet.

Anyone have an idea of what I should do to fix this?

Here is the output of ifconfig

```
Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
INET6 ADDR: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:4532 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:4532 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
RX bytes:335072 (335.0 KB) TX bytes:335072 (335.0 KB)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`?